# GroupBy multiple columns in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `shifts` collection like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647d"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-24T06:21:00.000Z"), //can be weekday, sat, sun
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-24T08:21:00.000Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32 //this wil vary based on **from** field
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647e"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-25T06:21:00.000Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-25T08:21:00.000Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647f"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-26T06:21:00.000Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-26T08:21:00.000Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
```

I want to be able to produce an output like this

### Job A (This can be obtained using jobId)

- Weekday earnings - $50 (2 * $25)
- Saturday earnings - $90 (3 * $30)
- Sunday earnings - $100 (2 * $50) Total earnings = $240

### Job B

- Weekday earnings..............

### Total earnings = Job A + Job B ..... = $X

Weekday or Saturday or Sunday can be derived from `from` field. For a Weekday, all days from Monday to Friday need to be grouped.
Number of hours can be derived by subtracting `from` from `to`.

So, I think the following needs to be done, but I am not able to implement in MongoDB

- Group by `jobId`, group by day extracted from `from` (also group all weekdays) and get the sum of hours extracted by subtracting `from` and  `to`.
- Finally, get the sum of all the above sums to get the total earnings
- Get the final sum of all job earnings.

I found a few similar questions but I am not able to apply it to my situation
[mongodb group values by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields)
[Mongodb Aggregation Framework | Group over multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418985/mongodb-aggregation-framework-group-over-multiple-values)
[How to group by multiple columns and multiple values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026941/how-to-group-by-multiple-columns-and-multiple-values-in-mongodb)

USE CASE:
When a user visits a page called earnings, I need to show him the earnings for the last week for each job and total earnings (then he can change the date range). So, I intent the show the split up for each Job, further split by weekday, saturday and sunday earnings and total earnings and work hours for *THAT* job. And final total earnings which is a summation of all the individual job earnings.

P.S I am using MongoDB 3.4

Comment: Rather than downvoting, make helpful comments or edits so that beginners can at least understand and not get discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below aggregation query:

```
db.shifts.aggregate([{ 
    //this get the day of week and converts them into sunday, saturday
    $project: {
        jobId:1,
        hourlyRate:1, 
        dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$from" }, 
        workedHours: {$divide:[{ $subtract: ["$to", "$from"] }, 3600000]}, 
        saturday:{$floor: {$divide:[{ $dayOfWeek: "$from" }, 7]}},
        sunday:{$floor: {$divide:[{$abs:{$subtract:[{ $dayOfWeek: "$from" }, 7]}}, 6]}},
    }
}, {
    //based on the values of sunday and saturday gets the value of weekday
    $project: {
        jobId:1,
        workedHours:1,
        hourlyRate:1,
        saturday:1,
        sunday: 1,
        weekday:{$abs: {$add:["$sunday","$saturday", -1]}},
    } 
}, {
    //here calculates the earnings for each job
    $group:{
        _id:"$jobId",
        sundayEarnings:{$sum: {$multiply:["$sunday", "$hourlyRate", "$workedHours"]}},
        saturdayEarnings:{$sum: {$multiply:["$saturday", "$hourlyRate", "$workedHours"]}},
        weekdayEarnings:{$sum: {$multiply:["$weekday", "$hourlyRate", "$workedHours"]}},
        totalEarnings: {$sum:{$multiply:["$hourlyRate", "$workedHours"]}},
        totalWorkedHours: {$sum: "$workedHours"}
    }
}, {
    //and finally calculates the total jobs earnings
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        jobs:{$push:{
            jobId: "$_id",
            sundayEarnings: "$sundayEarnings",
            saturdayEarnings: "$saturdayEarnings",
            weekdayEarnings: "$weekdayEarnings",
            totalEarnings: "$totalEarnings",
            totalWorkedHours: "$totalWorkedHours"
        }},
        totalJobsEarning: {$sum: "$totalEarnings"}
    }
}])
```

1. The first `$project` aggregation gives either **0 or 1** values to `saturday` and `sunday` based on the `dayOfWeek` value by making several arithmetic calculations.
2. Second `$project` aggregation calculates the `weekday`'s value based on the `saturday` and `sunday` values.
3. The first `$group` calculates the earnings for each day in each job.
4. Finally the second `$group` aggregation calculates the sum of earnings of all the jobs.

**Test**

This is my input:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647d"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-24T06:21:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-24T08:21:00Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647e"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-25T06:21:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-25T08:21:00Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885a1108c2fc432d649647f"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-26T06:21:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-26T08:21:00Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58870cfd59dfb6b0c4eadd72"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-28T06:21:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-28T08:21:00Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58870dc659dfb6b0c4eadd73"),
    "from" : ISODate("2017-01-29T06:21:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2017-01-29T08:21:00Z"),
    "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
    "hourlyRate" : 32
}
```

The above aggregation query gives the following output:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "jobs" : [
        {
            "jobId" : ObjectId("586d7d6acfc7e05669d6e2c8"),
            "sundayEarnings" : 64,
            "saturdayEarnings" : 64,
            "weekdayEarnings" : 192,
            "totalEarnings" : 320,
            "totalWorkedHours" : 10 
        }
    ],
    "totalJobsEarning" : 320
}
```

In the `jobs` array there is only one job because the docs of shifts collection is referenced to the same `jobId`. You can try this with different `jobId`s and it will give you different jobs with total earnings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the above query does not work. This is the output that I got `[{"_id":null,"jobs":[{"sundayEarnings":0,"saturdayEarnings":0,"weekdayEarnings":210,"totalEarnings":210},{"sundayEarnings":0,"saturdayEarnings":0,"weekdayEarnings":720,"totalEarnings":720},{"sundayEarnings":57.6,"saturdayEarnings":0,"weekdayEarnings":256,"totalEarnings":313.6}],"totalJobsEarning":1243.6}]`. As you can see, first of all the jobId is missing from each object, saturday and sunday earnings are shown as 0 in 2nd and 3rd objects which is incorrect for my collection.

Comment: Also, I need the total hours worked for each job which is missing. Thanks :). Can you please update....

Comment: I have update the question to add the use case for a better understanding

Comment: I've updated my answer and the suggested query as well. You have got 0 earnings for saturday and sunday values, because in your provided input there is only weekday working hours. I've used your provided input and also  added another docs for sunday and saturday and works fine (check the output of my post).

Answer (score 0):

Using the **[`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#exp._S_switch)** operator to build up an expression of case statements to evaluate earnings, you can run the following pipeline to get the desired result

```
var hoursWorked = { 
    "$divide": [
        { "$subtract": ["$to", "$from"] }, 
        3600000
    ]
};

db.collection('shifts').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "jobId": { "$in": [jobA_id, jobB_id] },
            "from": { "$gte": new Date() }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "totalEarnings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$switch": {
                        "branches": [
                            {
                                "case": { 
                                    "$not": { 
                                        "$in": [
                                            { "$dayOfWeek": "$from" }, 
                                            [1, 7] 
                                        ] 
                                    } 
                                }, 
                                "then": { "$multiply": [hoursWorked, 20] }
                            },
                            { 
                                "case": { 
                                    "$eq": [
                                        { "$dayOfWeek": "$from" }, 
                                        7
                                    ] 
                                }, 
                                "then": { "$multiply": [hoursWorked, 25] }
                            },
                            { 
                                "case": { 
                                    "$eq": [
                                        { "$dayOfWeek": "$from" }, 
                                        1 
                                    ] 
                                }, 
                                "then": { "$multiply": [hoursWorked, 30] } 
                            }
                        ]
                        "default": 0
                    }   
                } 
            }              
        }
    }       
], function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
    console.log(results[0].totalEarnings); 
});
```

Comment: It correctly yields the `totalEarnings` but I also need the split up per Job as mentioned in the question. For each job, I need `weedayEarnings`, `saturdayEarnings`, `sundayEarnings`, `totalHours` and `totalEarnings`. And then a final `totalEarnings` and `totalHours` which is combined for all the jobs.

Comment: Also, the switch case is not needed at all in the query you provided, since we already have a field called `hourlyRate`. So you can multiply hours worked with `hourlyRate`.

Comment: I have update the question to add the use case for a better understanding